# Was Senegal involved in the 1918 Russian Revolution?

Tags: russian-revolution

In the 1923 novel "[The White Guard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_White_Guard)" by Mikhail Bulgakov there is a scene where Russian officers are lamenting that the Senegalese have yet to arrive on the battle front to help them (p. 44). They infer that they are forces from Africa so I assume they mean from the country Senegal.

I have the impression that the novel is a realistic account of the war (I haven't finished it yet) so I wonder if this detail is based on any fact. Did Senegal send forces to aid the imperial regime in the 1918 Russian Revolution?

Comment: Check [Southern Russia intervention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Southern_Russia_intervention)

Comment: Welcome to History:SE. Could you edit your question to clarify what you've looked into already, complete with links and references, and context if applicable? In particular, please let us know what you find missing or unclear about the Wikipedia entry on the topic, if one exists. This allows those who might want to answer to do so without needing to redo the work you've already done. You might find it helpful to review the site tour and Help Centre and, in particular, How to Ask.

Comment: At that time Senegal was a French colony, and any Senegalese soldiers would have been part of the French army,

Comment: Mark C. Wallace,  My Google search returned nothing specific on my question so I posted my question here. Lars's link to the Wikipedia page was just about what I was looking for-- I hadn't heard of the Southern Russian intervention.

Comment: I've heard about the 1917 revolution. Was there another one the next year?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this article is a picture of French colonial troops in Ukraine: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Southern_Russia_intervention

It also mentions: “By 14 April there were only 5,000 allied soldiers in , including 2,000 Greek and 1,500 Algerian and Senegalese troops.“

The men in the picture might be Senegalese fighting for France.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Senegalese_Tirailleurs
The above link says: “Despite recruitment not being limited to Senegal, these infantry units took on the adjective "sénégalais" since that was where the first black African Tirailleur regiment had been formed.“

Comment: I see Lars posted the same link.